# summarize weekly average using daily data in R

Tags: r, mean, lag, summarize, dplyr

How to add one column price.wk.average to the data such that price.wk.average is equal to the average price of last week, and also add one column price.mo.average to the data such that it equals to the average price of last month? The price.wk.average will be the same for the entire week.

```
 Dates    Price   Demand  Price.wk.average   Price.mo.average
 2010-1-1   x        x
 2010-1-2   x        x
 ......
  2015-1-1  x         x
```

Comment: Hi @jkl Please consider accepting an answer below (clicking check mark to left of answer), one that worked for you. This lets the community know that it worked.

Answer (score 5):

jkl,

try to post reproducible examples.  It will make it easier to help you.  you can use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2017-1-1"),by="day",length.out = 100), price = round(runif(100)*100+50,0))
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(week = week(date)) %>%
  mutate(Price.wk.average = mean(price)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(month = month(date)) %>%
  mutate(Price.mo.average = mean(price))
```

Answer (score 5):

(Since I don't have enough points to comment)

I wanted to point out that Eric's answer will not distinguish average weekly price by year. Therefore, if you are interested in unique weeks (Week 1 of 2012 != Week 1 of 2015 ), you will need to do extra work to group by unique weeks.

```
df <- data.frame( Dates = c("2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2015-01-3"),
                  Price = c(50, 20, 40) )

      Dates Price
1  2010-1-1    50
2  2010-1-2    20
3 2015-01-3    40
```

Just to keep your data frame tidy, I suggest converting dates to POSIX format then sorting the data frame:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% 
      mutate(Dates = lubridate::parse_date_time(Dates,"ymd")) %>% 
      arrange( Dates )
```

To group by unique weeks:

```
df <- df %>% 
      group_by( yw = paste( year(Dates), week(Dates)))
```

Then mutate and ungroup.

To group by unique months:

```
df <- df %>% 
      group_by( ym = paste( year(Dates), month(Dates)))
```

and mutate and ungroup.

Comment: exactly.  i want to group it by day..this will solve the problem.